# Accessing an object by a specific key

Tags: javascript

I am querying a database and it is returning all of the objects in a collection called contracts. These contracts are simple objects with keys and values. Such as

```
{
name: BOB,
title: theinternet
date: {...}
}
```

I would like to check specific keys in each of the objects but I am not sure how to properly describe how these objects are grouped together, and I don't know how to access any of the data inside of this collection of objects.

```
console.log(contracts)
returns  

Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ] this spreads to 


(4) […]
​
0: Object { id: "1K19Q7tXIM2yJih7Qj4y", amount: "123421", company: "43214", … }
​
1: Object { id: "MvEr5t9Sd0oqDyajN9rl", amount: "663425", company: "tewq", … }
​
2: Object { id: "ckgOLDU6RdstsIoraKiy", amount: "123421", company: "43214", … }
​
3: Object { id: "jr6XjkAntRucmx0EPeQC", amount: "134", company: "rewq", … }
```

However, when I `console.log(typeof contracts)` it says it's an object.

I was able to get the size of the object correctly by doing the following... but I don't know how to search for a specific key in that object.

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
        var size = 0, key;
        for (key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
        }
        return size;
    };
    console.log(Object.size(contracts))

returns 4
```

Once I have all of the objects I would like to be able to if(obj.title === 'theinternet' then do something. But I am unfamiliar with de-structuring this type of object.

Comment: `Array` in JS is of type `object` (confusingly), but it has a `length` property you could use instead of your `Object.size` function

Comment: @thedude If I try to do console.log(contracts.length) It throws an error saying that contracts doesn't exist.

Comment: that means `contracts` does not exist when you try to `console.log` it, not the `length` property

Comment: @thedude If I remove the .length from  console.log(contracts.length) and just print contracts, it prints out all of the contracts. I am very confused.

Comment: me too... If you want you can ask a separate question and provide some more details there

Comment: @thedude If I Console.log(contracts) it prints out all of the contracts, however, if I console.log(contracts.length) or size or contracts[0] or anything other than just (contracts) by itself, it says that contracts is undefined. Is it possible that because contracts is making a request to a database and the data isn't there at the start and that is why the program is failing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201284/discussion-between-thedude-and-aaron-etheridge).

Comment: this is a Firebase collection, which is a NoSql. How would I format this into a normal javascript object?

Comment: If you're pulling data from a database, chances are it's asynchronous. That means the next line of code after the pull will run before the data has been retrieved, which would explain your undefined error. Make sure that wherever you're using `contracts`, the variable both exists and has been loaded first. (Console logs sometimes take some time to print, meaning just printing contracts might be printing after it's loaded, but the console.log code was before it was loaded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
let newObj = contracts.filter(item => item.title === 'theinternet')
```

Comment: This would be syntactically incorrect. Either should be implicit return `contracts.filter(item => item.title === 'theinternet')` or `return` with curly braces `contracts.filter(item => { return item.title === 'theinternet' })`

Comment: I get contracts is undefined when I try this method. I feel as though this object is not a traditional object but I'm not sure.

Comment: @AaronEtheridge This assumes that you set your object variable name to `contracts`. You can set it to whatever you like or pass the object itself into the function. Based on the data you posted, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it, if you only want one item like firstOrDefault on linq you will use **find()**, if you want all the items that match your **Id** you will use **filter()**. You can also use map or anything else but filter or find will make more sense.

```
var data = [{
        'id': '1K19Q7tXIM2yJih7Qj4y',
        'amount': '123421',
        'company': '43214'
   },
   {
        'id': 'MvEr5t9Sd0oqDyajN9rl',
        'amount': '663425',
        'company': 'tewq'
   },
   {
        'id': 'ckgOLDU6RdstsIoraKiy',
        'amount': '123421',
        'company': '43214'
   },
   {
        'id': 'jr6XjkAntRucmx0EPeQC',
        'amount': '134',
        'company': 'rewq'
   }
   ];

   function filterObject(filterParam) 
   {
    return data.filter(a=> a.id == filterParam)
   }
```

> Pass the parameter on here.

```
   console.log(filterObject('1K19Q7tXIM2yJih7Qj4y'));
```

This way will return all the items, try using **find()** too.